# Execute sequencial queries in Spring Data Mongodb Reactive

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I have to found All documents in collection B not referenced in collection A.

Using the method in ReactiveMongoRepository

```
Flux<A> findAll();
```

So I made this code:

```
collectionARepository.findAll()
    .flatMap(d -> d.documentBID())
    .collectList()
    .flatMap(list -> collectionBRepository.findDocsNotIn(list))
    .flatMap(b -> log.info(b.id())
    .subscribe();
```

But, if there's no documents in collection A, the second query will not be executed. How can I force the execution of second to get all documents.

Comment: That's interesting. Empty flux returns an empty list inside a Mono after you call `collectList`, so the subsequent `flatMap` should be executed. Did you check if it is really skipped.

Comment: You enlightened my ideas. I was thinking in Flux, not a Mono after `collectList` ...

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

My IDE for some reason was not show error, but When I use `collectList` I passed from Flux to Mono. When I call flatMap (It should show an error) I cannot return a Flux, only a Mono. That causes an Exception and It was treat like "Entity not found". My bad.

So here is my final code:

```
collectionARepository.findAll()
    .flatMap(d -> d.documentBID())
    .collectList()
    .flatMapMany(list -> collectionBRepository.findDocsNotIn(list))
    .flatMap(b -> log.info(b.id())
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: if writing a webflux application you should not call subscribe yourself unless you are the subscriber. Usually the subscriber is the calling client.